# Convert a javascript piece of code into php

Tags: php, javascript

I just want to properly translate this

```
foo.push(("000" + parseInt(foo1.charAt(loc3), 16).toString(2)).slice(-4));
```

into php.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$foo[] = substr("000" . decbin(hexdec(substr($foo1, $loc3, 1))), -4);
```

Untested, but should either work or get you close.

Comment: I got a parse error again. Try this: `$foo[] = substr("000" . decbin(hexdec(substr($foo1, $loc3, 1))), -4);`   +1 anyway though because other that that error this looks good!

Comment: @mmmshuddup, thank you for your help... I'm not posting on my dev computer.  :-D

Comment: :P any time, I know how that goes!